# Flutter google maps and firebase not working together

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, flutter, dart

I am using google map and firebase in my app but app does not compile and throws following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' is set to compileOnly/provided 
which is not supported
```

**Following is my app/build.gradle file**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
   }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
   throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the 
   local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.squadtechs.www.bus_tracking_app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Following is my module level build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**POINTS TO REMEMBER**

1. I have migrated to androidX but still issue persists
2. If I use firebase alone or google maps alone, it works fine but not together

Comment: Looks like there is a dependency conflicts between firebase and messaging packages, try to downgrade?

Comment: tried but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `firebase auth` dependency in your app level `build.gradle` file like following

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks @Aneeq, I will check and let you know

Comment: Works fine, I added Auth dependency in `app/buils.gradle` it worked, added maps dependency (as answered by @Ali), it worked. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `app/build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

Comment: It works, I don't know why but it solved my issue, same for @Aneeq's asnwer

Answer (score 3):

You need to add native dependency for `FirebaseAuth` in your app level `build.gradle` file like following:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'`

or

You can put `Google Maps` dependency in the same file as well like :
`implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you migrated to androidX manually. Try to replace these lines in `app/build.gradle`:

```
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

to:

```
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

and

```
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

to:

```
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

Comment: Adding dependency for `firebaseauth` or `maps` solved it